# Rails 3.1 cookies - subdomain app can't see wildcard cookie in dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have set a cookie to work across the subdomains in my app.

The url for the setting app is "http://tu2"

It sets the following cookie

```
cookies[:tuppt] = {
  :value => "foobar",
  :domain => ".tu2"
}
```

The url for the other app is "http://account.tu2"

For some reason, this cookie is not visible on the account app.

Any ideas why this would be?  Is there a problem with using these non-standard domains?

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding .com to both of these domains and it works.  I guess the domain needs to have a valid top-level domain.